# Binary response via Google Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I would like to **response binary**(image) via **Google Cloud Functions**.

I attempted to solve it as follows:

```
// .ts
import {Request, Response} from "express";

export function gif(req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.contentType("image/gif");
    res.send(new Buffer("[Here is image data encoded by base64]", "base64"));
}
```

However, the response of its function is follows:

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[71,73,...]} // not binary but JSON
```

This code works fine with express, but it does not work with Cloud Functions. Is this a bug? or is there another way?

Comment: I'm not sure if you should be sending base64 here. What I've done in one of my projects and what works: `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}); res.write(data.toString('binary'), 'binary'); res.end();`

Comment: Thank you for your replying.
Your codes works successfully! (in the both of remote and cloud-functions-emulator).
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem thanks to commenting.
I will summarize the results here.

successfully final codes:

```
import {Request, Response} from "express";

export function track(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const data = new Buffer("[Here is image data encoded by base64]", "base64");
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/gif"});
    res.write(data.toString("binary"), "binary");
    res.end();
}
```

My purpose is to create a JavaScript-independent tracking function, and responsing image is small size and meaningless.